# Implementing a custom Android View library component. Where to put drawables?

Tags: android, view, jar

I'm developing a custom Android view which i want to be reused. I want to implement it as a shared jar library.

My view needs some drawable resources and i'm wondering where is the proper place to store them, as the common /res/drawable-* project folder is not suitable, as it is a seperate library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make an [Android Library Project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject), rather than a straight Jar if you want to include application resources.